# Manage Navbar's menus efficiently

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I´m starting to go a bit deeper with JHipster and I´m looking for a **efficient way of managing menus which should only be shown if a user is logged**.

I thought about several ways of managing it, but all of them require the use of backend part, and I´m pretty sure it should be a better way for solving the problem using only frontend part. I imagine that the key could be related to a line similar to this one: "ng-class="{active: vm.$state.includes('admin')}"". But I don't have experience dealing with states at frontend's and I´m getting lost.

Could any one provide me some info with it?

Comment: Another idea I had is to use "has-authority" for doing this validation, but I would like to know something more related to session, or login

Comment: I don't understand your objection about "has-authority" this is exactly what this is made for and is totally related to session and login.

Comment: Hi Gaël, It´s because in some cases is enough using "has-authority" or "has-any-authority", but in some other cases I´m trying to do something related to user. For example access to an user's personal page which should be public but only the user or an admin could edit it, and is in this last cases where I didn't found the key to implement at frontend part a way to develop that "owner" relation.

Comment: It looks like you may need dynamic roles which is a feature that Deepu wants to implement, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1995 but you coul also do it simply by adding a function to your menu controller that you would use with ng-hide.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Gaël, I'll check both possible solutions and implement the one that better fix. Regards.